# Hiding Report Columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

My gut is no, but if there's a Crystal Guru out there that knows better here's my question.  I have a report with 12 columns.  At times the report needs to be run for a crowd that doesn't have the "need to know" on a couple of the columns.  The specific column(s) to hide can change from time to time depending on the circumstances.

Is there a way to give the end user of the report the ability to toggle columns on or off without me having to hand code all the different options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is.  Set up a boolean parameter for each column.  Then place that parameter in the suppress formula of each column.  That allows the end user to uncheck any columns they do not want to appear in the final report.

Comment: can you tell how to writ formaula to suppress the column

Comment: I'd post as a new question.  It's hard to ask a detailed question or give a detailed answer in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to build the report with all of the field, but optimize it for Excel.